# `has no default export` When trying to compile Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to recompile my Webpack Ng4 project after a hiatus and I get

```
ERROR in ..../src/typescript/my-routing.module.ts
(1,8): error TS1192: Module '".../src/typescript/home/home.component"' has no default export.

ERROR in .../typescript/my-routing.module.ts
(2,8): error TS1192: Module '".../node_modules/@angular/router/router"' has no default export.

ERROR in .../src/typescript/my-routing.module.ts
(3,8): error TS1192: Module '".../node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no default export.

ERROR in ./src/typescript/main.ts
(5,8): error TS1192: Module '".../node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no default export.
```

I solved this elsewhere using the default keyword but is there a way I can ignore this here?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make sure and wrap my Class names in `{}`

So instead of say....

`import NgModule from "@angular/core";`

I now NEED the squigglies

`import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";`

So apparently you can't avoid the squigglies anymore unless you use the default keyword.

Comment: or you can do like `import * from "@angular/core"` if you want to add all classes.